# SESSION_COOKIE_AGE, вечная сессия

Tags: python, django

Посмотрел, что  в документации SESSION_COOKIE_AGE отвечает за время сессии. В какое значение нужно поставить, чтобы сессия никогда не закрывалась? Видимо, None?

Comment: Вечные сессии это плохо, переполнят базу и создадут риски безопасности в случае возможной утечки кук

Comment: спасибо, понятно